# Log4j delete logs older than one month

Tags: java, log4j

I have the following Log4J configurations, how I can delete the logs older than one month?

> ## Define the root logger with appender file
>
> log =log/
>
> log4j.rootLogger = ERROR, FILE
>
> ## Define the file appender
>
> log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
>
> ## Set the name of the file
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.File=${log}/server.log
>
> ## Set the immediate flush to true (default)
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
>
> ## Set the threshold to debug mode
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.Threshold=debug
>
> ## Set the append to false, should not overwrite
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.Append=true
>
> ## Set the DatePattern
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.DatePattern='.' yyyy-MM-dd-a
>
> ## Define the layout for file appender
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
>
> log4j.appender.FILE.layout.conversionPattern=%m%n

Comment: i dont think there is any thing of this kind ,you need to delete manually or make an app to do it for you

Answer (score 0):

you need to use RollingFileAppender and set the MaxBackupIndex count.